# How can i make Autocomplete similar to Dropdown?

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I have made a autocomplete control as given below.

```
var PrimaryPhy = <?php include('getdata.php'); ?>;
        $("#PatientID").autocomplete({
            source: PrimaryPhy,
            autoFocus:true
        });
```

getdata.php

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","***","***");

if(!$con){
die("Error : ".mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("DBname",$con);

$patient_info = array();
$result = mysql_query("select * from tablename");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$patient_info[] = $row['Name'];
}
echo json_encode($patient_info);

?>
```

Here I have brought all the Name information of all records from the table. But i wanted to do like Dropdown with option values. 
For example :

`<option value="1">Item 1</option>`

Likewise i need to bring the primary key ID of the table as a value for that item. How can i achieve that?

And also If i place one more autocomplete control next to this control, How can i make that first autocomplete's output as a input to the second autocomplete's input?

Comment: Do you want post them and for this reason you want to declare them as options?

Comment: You will have to do an ajax call for that. you have got json object so you can create a dropdown using jQuery/javascript and push all values using an each loop

Comment: See this link if this helps: http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

Comment: I have done ajax call, but POST was not working fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish it by `<datalist>`.

The `<datalist>` element, a new addition in the HTML5 specification, allows developers to create native autocomplete dropdowns for their web applications.

The `<datalist>` element is used to specify all of the possible values for the autocomplete list like below:

```
<datalist id="languages">
  <option value="HTML">
  <option value="CSS">
  <option value="JavaScript">
</datalist>
```

For detailed example, you can check [here](http://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/jKnzG)